# MYSQL JOIN between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need some help. I have 2 tables

```
Table1                      Table2
id | user_id                id | user_id | device_token 
1    4                      1        4      7854239213
2    5                      2        4      1232131232
3    9                      3        5      1232132131
                            4        5        1231321312
```

I need to make a query that will take first id from table1 and all device_token for that table1.user_id, but without select in select. I need a query with joins.
Expected result:

```
user_id => 4 
device_token => 7854239213

user_id => 4 
device_token => 1232131232
```

Comment: No need to aske on SO, seems you just need to look for [something like this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have `user_id` from 1 to 9

```
SELECT T1.USER_ID,T2.DEVICE_TOKEN FROM
TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN
TABLE2 T2 ON T1.USER_ID=T2.USER_ID WHERE T1.USER_ID=FLOOR(RAND(1)*10)
```

Comment: I want to get just one id from table1 not all of them.

Comment: could you post your query ? and expected output ?

Comment: My query is the same with your query, but the problem is that I want to get randomly one user_id from table1 and all device_token belonging to that user_id

Comment: Hmm...after proccessing the user I am deleting the row, so next time this user_id will not be

Comment: I am thinking that everytime to get the first user_id, but I don`t know how.

Comment: you said.. random.. now saying first user.. what do you want actually ?

Comment: I am thinking wich is best alternative, because after proccessing the user, I will delete it from table1

Comment: You are not clear with your requirement and you have posted a question ?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

`SELECT Table2.user_id, Table2.device_token FROM Table2 JOIN Table1 on Table1.user_id = Table2.user_id`

And if you want a specific ID:

`SELECT Table2.user_id, Table2.device_token FROM Table2 JOIN Table1 on Table1.user_id = Table2.user_id WHERE Table2.user_id = 4`

I highly recommend you read this excellent SitePoint article for a beginners introduction to MySQL joins:

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

select device_token.table2 from table1,table2 where table1.id=table2.id and table1.user_id=table2.user_id and table1.user_id=4;

Comment: FIrst user_id everytime is different, after I am proccessing that user I will delete it and I will take next one